quote in pyrogram Telegram
How do I write a quote in Telegram like this?
enter image description here



@app.on_message()

async def send_quoted_message(client, message):

    await app.send_message(

        chat_id=message.chat.id,

        text=('> TesT'), 

        parse_mode='markdown'

        )


The Pyrogram library hasn't been updated in about a year. Consequently, any new features or Markdown styles are not supported by the original Pyrogram library. However, you can use one of the updated or actively maintained forks of the library, such as KurimuzonAkuma/pyrogram. By installing this fork you'll have access to all the latest features without needing to make any modifications.
In this documentation, you will find instructions on how to install this fork.
After installing this fork this code will function.
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.enums import ParseMode

app = Client(...)

@app.on_message()
async def send_quoted_message(client, message):
    await app.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        text=('> TesT'), 
        parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN
        )

